# Optimization: constructive solution

Tags: optimization

Consider the following program
\begin{align}
\max_{x,y \geq 0} f(x,y)\tag{1}
\end{align}

I wanna construct a solution with $y^* = 0$ and $x^* > 0$. 
Suppose FOCs satisfy
\begin{align}
f_x(x^*,y^*) = 0\\
f_y(x^*,y^*) < 0
\end{align}

and SOCs also satisfy
\begin{align}
f_{xx}(x^*,y^*) < 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \det(H(f)(x^*,y^*)) > 0
\end{align}

where $H(\cdot)$ is the hessian.

- Is $(x^*,y^*)$ a solution of $(1)$?

Comment: It seems to me we need to know a bit more about $f(.,.)$. Is it continuous? Strictly concave (not just at the point but elsewhere)?

Comment: Oh yeah, it's continuous and quasi-concave.

Comment: I was able to verify the constructed analytcal solution by a numerical approximation. Is this somehow proof?